# A Database connection using "Mysql" was missing or unable to connect

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

My code is executing properly on development. But on production gives following error:

> Missing Database Connection
>
> Error: A Database connection using "Mysql" was missing or unable to connect.
>   The database server returned this error: Selected driver is not enabled
>
> Error: Mysql driver is NOT enabled

Answer (score 0):

Mysql extension on PHP 5.5.x and above is deprecated. 
On PHP 7 mysql has been removed.
You should use PDO. If you can't, then try to replace your mysql with mysqli extension.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but it resolved with this

```
yum install --enablerepo=remi,remi-php70 php-mysqlnd
```